# Using different random number ranges depending on which array a corresponding element belongs to

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Sorry about the wordy title, I couldn't think how best to phrase this. (if anyone has a better title idea for the underlying principle let me know!)

So, I've got 2 arrays for a 'random workout app'.  In the 'generate workout' function, I'm generating a random number of exercises, picking them at random, and then assigning a number of reps to each exercise (again, randomly).

I've got it working fine but there are some exercises that suit a high number of reps (push ups might suit an arc4random between 10 - 30 say) and some that suit a low number of reps (a 1 mile run would suit an arc 4 random between 1 - 5 say).

In creating my workout, I now need to essentially check "if the exercise element in position [0] belongs to the 'low reps array' use reps key X, if it belongs to 'high reps array' use reps key Y.

I think I can do the random number generating bit but I'm massively stuck on the whole checking piece.

Here's my code (with pseudo code explaining in a bit more context hopefully what I'm trying to achieve)

```
let highRepsArray = ["push ups", "star jumps", "watch tv"]
let lowRepsArray = ["500m row", "3 mile run", "lift a truck"]
let finalExerciseArray = highRepsArray + lowRepsArray
//create function for number of exercises in this specific workout

func generateNewWorkout() -> (randomExerciseArray:Set<String>, randomRepsArray:[Int]) {

    let randomKey = Int(arc4random_uniform(4) + 3)
    var workoutSet = Set<String>()
    let possibleExercises = finalExerciseArray
    var repsSet = [Int]()

    while workoutSet.count < (randomKey) {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(possibleExercises.count)))
        workoutSet.insert(possibleExercises[randomIndex])
    }

//generate the reps array by counting through the same random key used to generate the number of exercises

    while repsSet.count < (randomKey) {

//here's what i can't work out!

        IF THE EXERCISE AT POSITION [0] IS IN EXERCISEARRAY1 THEN CHOOSE A RANDOM NUMBER FROM 1 - 10, IF IN EXERCISE ARRAY2 CHOOSE FROM 5 - 10 AND APPEND IT IN THAT POSITION
        IF THE EXERCISE AT POSITION [1] IS IN EXERCISEARRAY1 THEN CHOOSE A RANDOM NUMBER FROM 1 - 10, IF IN EXERCISE ARRAY2 CHOOSE FROM 5 - 10 AND APPEND IT IN THAT POSITION

//append the rep number into the array - here it's just the same range for every exercise, but I need to split this out as above
        repsSet.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(20)+10))
    }
```

This is nearly the last thing I need to do that I can't workout before my app is finished so hoping someone can help! :-)

Comment: Don't use just String. Create a custom struct/object with a name property, and another difficulty (which can be a custom enum), and read the difficulty property of your object to know how many time the user can repeat that excersie.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is wrong for your needs. You need to use a custom struct that holds the exercise name AND the suitable range of reps. It is then trivial to generate a random number from within that range.

Comment: okay thanks - is there any chance you could post a very simple idea of how this would look?  Would that change my array as well i.e. (exerciseName = "Squat", RepRange = 0-10) or something?  (don't expect you to do the full thing of course but I'm very new to this!)

Comment: Start with an array of all exercises (the struct). Shuffle it. Deal off the first few of them. Now you have your random exercises. For each one, the struct gives you its name, to show the user, and the range, to calculate a random number of reps.